# What is the difference between "[dict()] * n" and a "for loop with .append(dict())"?

Tags: python, dictionary, collections

I'm implementing a DFS algorithm and I want to create a list of dictionaries. But I found that if I use `[dict()] * n`, I got unexpected result.

I'm not sure what is the difference between "`[dict()] * n`" and a "`for` loop with `.append(dict())`".

Any hint is appreciated.

```py
def DFS1(nums, level, target, dp):
    if level == len(nums):
        if target == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    if target in dp[level]:
        return dp[level][target]

    cnt1 = DFS1(nums, level + 1, target + nums[level], dp)
    cnt2 = DFS1(nums, level + 1, target - nums[level], dp)
    dp[level][target] = cnt1 + cnt2
    return cnt1 + cnt2
```

test code is:

```py
nums = [1,1,1,1,1]
n = len(nums)
target = -3
#dp = [dict()] * n   #<== This does not work as expected
dp = []
for i in range(0, n):
    dp.append(dict())

resCnt = DFS1(nums, 0, target, dp)
print(resCnt)
```

Comment: Thats this behaviour https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What basically happens is that you are creating references:

```
x = [dict()] * 10
print x
>[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]  #looks fine

x[0]['x'] = 3                              #all references share same memory
print x
[{'x': 3}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 3}, {'x': 3}]
```

**Visually following happens:**

[image]

To avoid `referencing`, you have to explicitly tell python to create new dictionaries every time:

```
x = [{} for x in range(10)]
print x
>[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
x[0]['x'] = 3
print x
>[{'x': 3}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

**Visual Representation:** Every bucket has it's **own copy** of the dict:

[image]

Comment: Crystal clear! Really appreciated!